# Numpy outperforms Tensorflow and Pytorch with same hyperparameters

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch

I have made 3 Neural Networks for [Joel's FizzBuzz implementation](http://joelgrus.com/2016/05/23/fizz-buzz-in-tensorflow/), each in Numpy, TensorFlow and Pytorch. With the same hyperparameters and 1k epochs, my numpy script converges to 0.002 loss yet my pytorch and tensorflow is still jumping around 0.6. Could someone please help me figure out whats happening. I dont think Google and [Facebook + Nvidia] made something dump than Numpy just for GPU boost. My code below

#### Numpy

```
import numpy as np

input_size = 10
epochs = 1000
batches = 64
lr = 0.01


def sig(val):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-val))


def sig_d(val):
    sig_val = sig(val)
    return sig_val * (1 - sig_val)


def binary_enc(num):
    ret = [int(i) for i in '{0:b}'.format(num)]
    return [0] * (input_size - len(ret)) + ret


def binary_dec(array):
    ret = 0
    for i in array:
        ret = ret * 2 + int(i)
    return ret


def training_test_gen(x, y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    indices = np.random.permutation(range(len(x)))
    split_size = int(0.9 * len(indices))
    trX = x[indices[:split_size]]
    trY = y[indices[:split_size]]
    teX = x[indices[split_size:]]
    teY = y[indices[split_size:]]
    return trX, trY, teX, teY


def x_y_gen():
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(1000):
        x.append(binary_enc(i))
        if i % 15 == 0:
            y.append([1, 0, 0, 0])
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            y.append([0, 1, 0, 0])
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            y.append([0, 0, 1, 0])
        else:
            y.append([0, 0, 0, 1])
    return training_test_gen(np.array(x), np.array(y))


def check_fizbuz(i):
    if i % 15 == 0:
        return 'fizbuz'
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        return 'buz'
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        return 'fiz'
    else:
        return 'number'


trX, trY, teX, teY = x_y_gen()

w1 = np.random.randn(10, 100)
w2 = np.random.randn(100, 4)

b1 = np.zeros((1, 100))
b2 = np.zeros((1, 4))

no_of_batches = int(len(trX) / batches)
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch in range(no_of_batches):
        # forward
        start = batch * batches
        end = start + batches
        x = trX[start:end]
        y = trY[start:end]
        a2 = x.dot(w1) + b1
        h2 = sig(a2)
        a3 = h2.dot(w2) + b2
        hyp = sig(a3)
        error = hyp - y
        loss = (error ** 2).mean()

        # backward
        outerror = error
        outgrad = outerror * sig_d(a3)
        outdelta = h2.T.dot(outgrad)
        outbiasdelta = np.ones([1, batches]).dot(outgrad)

        hiddenerror = outerror.dot(w2.T)
        hiddengrad = hiddenerror * sig_d(a2)
        hiddendelta = x.T.dot(hiddengrad)
        hiddenbiasdelta = np.ones([1, batches]).dot(hiddengrad)

        w1 -= hiddendelta * lr
        b1 -= hiddenbiasdelta * lr
        w2 -= outdelta * lr
        b2 -= outbiasdelta * lr
    print(epoch, loss)

# test
a2 = teX.dot(w1) + b1
h2 = sig(a2)
a3 = h2.dot(w2) + b2
hyp = sig(a3)
outli = ['fizbuz', 'buz', 'fiz', 'number']
for i in range(len(teX)):
    num = binary_dec(teX[i])
    print(
        'Number: {} -- Actual: {} -- Prediction: {}'.format(
            num, check_fizbuz(num), outli[hyp[i].argmax()]))
print('Test loss: ', np.mean(teY - hyp))
```

#### Pytorch

```
import numpy as np
import torch as th
from torch.autograd import Variable


input_size = 10
epochs = 1000
batches = 64
lr = 0.01


def binary_enc(num):
    ret = [int(i) for i in '{0:b}'.format(num)]
    return [0] * (input_size - len(ret)) + ret


def binary_dec(array):
    ret = 0
    for i in array:
        ret = ret * 2 + int(i)
    return ret


def training_test_gen(x, y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    indices = np.random.permutation(range(len(x)))
    split_size = int(0.9 * len(indices))
    trX = x[indices[:split_size]]
    trY = y[indices[:split_size]]
    teX = x[indices[split_size:]]
    teY = y[indices[split_size:]]
    return trX, trY, teX, teY


def x_y_gen():
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(1000):
        x.append(binary_enc(i))
        if i % 15 == 0:
            y.append([1, 0, 0, 0])
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            y.append([0, 1, 0, 0])
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            y.append([0, 0, 1, 0])
        else:
            y.append([0, 0, 0, 1])
    return training_test_gen(np.array(x), np.array(y))


def check_fizbuz(i):
    if i % 15 == 0:
        return 'fizbuz'
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        return 'buz'
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        return 'fiz'
    else:
        return 'number'


trX, trY, teX, teY = x_y_gen()
if th.cuda.is_available():
    dtype = th.cuda.FloatTensor
else:
    dtype = th.FloatTensor
x = Variable(th.from_numpy(trX).type(dtype), requires_grad=False)
y = Variable(th.from_numpy(trY).type(dtype), requires_grad=False)

w1 = Variable(th.randn(10, 100).type(dtype), requires_grad=True)
w2 = Variable(th.randn(100, 4).type(dtype), requires_grad=True)

b1 = Variable(th.zeros(1, 100).type(dtype), requires_grad=True)
b2 = Variable(th.zeros(1, 4).type(dtype), requires_grad=True)

no_of_batches = int(len(trX) / batches)
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch in range(no_of_batches):
        start = batch * batches
        end = start + batches
        x_ = x[start:end]
        y_ = y[start:end]

        a2 = x_.mm(w1)
        a2 = a2.add(b1.expand_as(a2))
        h2 = a2.sigmoid()

        a3 = h2.mm(w2)
        a3 = a3.add(b2.expand_as(a3))
        hyp = a3.sigmoid()

        error = hyp - y_
        loss = error.pow(2).sum()
        loss.backward()

        w1.data -= lr * w1.grad.data
        w2.data -= lr * w2.grad.data
        b1.data -= lr * b1.grad.data
        b2.data -= lr * b2.grad.data
        w1.grad.data.zero_()
        w2.grad.data.zero_()
    print(epoch, error.mean().data[0])
```

#### TensorFlow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


input_size = 10
epochs = 1000
batches = 64
learning_rate = 0.01


def binary_enc(num):
    ret = [int(i) for i in '{0:b}'.format(num)]
    return [0] * (input_size - len(ret)) + ret


def binary_dec(array):
    ret = 0
    for i in array:
        ret = ret * 2 + int(i)
    return ret


def training_test_gen(x, y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    indices = np.random.permutation(range(len(x)))
    split_size = int(0.9 * len(indices))
    trX = x[indices[:split_size]]
    trY = y[indices[:split_size]]
    teX = x[indices[split_size:]]
    teY = y[indices[split_size:]]
    return trX, trY, teX, teY


def x_y_gen():
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(1000):
        x.append(binary_enc(i))
        if i % 15 == 0:
            y.append([1, 0, 0, 0])
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            y.append([0, 1, 0, 0])
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            y.append([0, 0, 1, 0])
        else:
            y.append([0, 0, 0, 1])
    return training_test_gen(np.array(x), np.array(y))


def check_fizbuz(i):
    if i % 15 == 0:
        return 'fizbuz'
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        return 'buz'
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        return 'fiz'
    else:
        return 'number'


trX, trY, teX, teY = x_y_gen()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 4], name='y')

lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [], name='lr')

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10, 100]))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([100, 4]))

b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(100))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(4))


a2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w1), b1))
hyp = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(a2, w2), b2))

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hyp - y))
optmizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr).minimize(cost)

prediction = tf.argmax(hyp, 1)

no_of_batches = int(len(trX) / batches)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        p = np.random.permutation(range(len(trX)))
        trX = trX[p]
        trY = trY[p]
        for batch in range(no_of_batches):
            start = batch * batches
            end = start + batches
            input_batch = trX[start: end]
            target_batch = trY[start: end]
            sess.run(
                optmizer, feed_dict={x: input_batch, y: target_batch, lr: learning_rate})
            if epoch % 100 == 0:
                a = np.argmax(teY, axis=1)
                b = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: teX})
                acc = np.mean(a == b)
                out_cost = sess.run(
                    cost, feed_dict={x: input_batch, y: target_batch, lr: learning_rate})
                print('cost - {} --- accuracy - {}'.format(out_cost.mean(), acc))
```

Comment: For TensorFlow, I am getting cost as ~1.5 and Accuracy around 0.60 for `epochs = 10000`, `batches = 100` * `learning_rate = 0.001`. What are you getting ?

Comment: If i increase the epoch or change the hyperparameter I can reduce the loss as the network is still learning. But my worry is my numpy loss is really less even with 1000 epoch and 64 batch with 0.01 learning rate. Here is my tensorflow loss --> 0.1552949845790863 
And this is my Numpy's --> 0.00912828950229

Comment: What's the accuracy for NumPy with 0.009 loss ?

Comment: @PirateX 0.984375

Answer (score 1):

Can't say I've checked all your code (that's too much work), but I noticed that you are not zeroing your bias gradients in PyTorch, so these gradients will keep growing, killing the optimization algorithm. (There may be other problems)

The more idiomatic way to write this would be:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr)

for _ in range(steps):

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # ...
```

As a general note, it shouldn't matter which framework you use here: numbers are numbers: if you feed the same batches, and initialize the weights the same way, you should get approximately the same gradients.

**Edit**

Here's another big difference: in NP, you are calculating the mean error (across batches and channels), while in PT, you sum them. That's a 40-fold difference that will affect both the loss and the gradient.

Comment: Oh mahn, I didn't see that mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. But that didn't change my network's behavior. Yes, what you said is what I am expecting and I am pretty sure, its my mistake.

Comment: Whats that, is it related to the error/loss calculation?